# fail to find header file when using Cocoapods version 1.0 - works fine with Cocoapods version 0.39

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to use libFLAC compiled to iOS in my project, using CocoaPod to install as a dependancy.

The trouble is the workspace is created just fine if I use CocoaPod version 0.39 but there is a build error if I use CocoaPod version 1.0  (see below for details about the error)

I'm using the project https://github.com/evature/flac-ios

My podfile contains:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/evature/Eva-Pods.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!
target 'ExampleApp' do
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '~>7.0'
    pod 'libFLAC', '~>1.3.0'
    pod 'RXPromise', '~>0.13.0'
end
```

The compile error is of a missing header file (inside the libFlac source) -

`#include "private/bitmath.h"` << 'private/bitmath.h' not found

This header file does exist in the Pods project under `Pods/libFlac/CorePrivateHeaders`

The libFlac podspec is at https://github.com/evature/Eva-Pods/blob/master/libFLAC/1.3.1/libFLAC.podspec

I'm using Xcode Version 7.3.1

I guess the blame is some breaking change between version 0.39 and version 1.0, but looking at the changelog and the Podspec I failed to find the breaking change.

Answer (score 2):

Did a quick test. I think you have to remove the "use_frameworks!" line from your podfile. Since none of the other libraries are built using Swift you should be fine.

Comment: I'mm having the same issue and I use libraries built with Swift, so this doesn't solve

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's caused by Xcode cache data. You can copy your project to a new file path and run to test this. Or delete the cache and run. This is how to delete:

1. Open Xcode Preference and select Locations:
   [image]
2. Click arrow to Derived Data, and delete all files in DeriveData folder:
   [image]
3. Run.